# QT HTML Parser (+XQuery)

Tags: html, qt, parsing, xpath, xquery

I'm looking for a QT HTML parser tool.
I have some html source code and I'd like to use XQuery on it.
I already tried using QWebPage + QWebElement, but I don't like this solution cause firstly it doesn't works on non-gui thread (because of QWebPage) and because we can't apply XPath but CSS Path.
The other solution I tried is QXmlQuery, it works great, but the only problem is that it doesn't works if there is an error on the page. For example, the first page I tried was missing systemId (in the DOCTYPE tag), so the parsing was aborted.

I heard we can use gecko for parsing but I have no idea how to use it with QT.

Have you some suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: What syntactical errors do you need to cope? I'm thinking about non-closed tags, missing `<html>` or `<head>` tags and so on... Note that most browsers cope these situations.

Comment: Yeah that kind of error, maybe missing namespaces, and incomplete DOCTYPE.

Comment: I finally ended up using libxml2. It does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use tidy on your HTML page and then process it with XQuery.

Zorba is a C++ XQuery processor that provides a tidy module.
You can find a live example at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#tQZu6aq1K4KoGJm9m0oIPwKRt04=

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at Zorba

Comment: I've a problem with your solution. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404480/zorba-with-tidy-module

Comment: I believe you can just set a text browser's HTML code in qt. That might help a bit even though this is old.

Answer (score 1):

BaseX got a [QT client](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex-api/tree/master/src/main/qt) and can use [TagSoup](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Parsers#HTML_Parser) for cleaning up HTML documents.

I'm sorry I cannot provide you with an QT example as I don't know QT at all.