# Zorba with tidy module

Tags: xquery, tidy, zorba

I'm trying to use the tidy module with zorba library (XQuery library), so I'd like to build zorba with tidy support.
I'm following the instructions at [this site](http://cf.zorba-xquery.com.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/zorba-0.9.8/zorba/html/util.html#tidyLib), but when I'm building it, cmake say me that ZORBA_WITH_TIDY was ignored. Do you know any way to include tidy in zorba ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tidy is an external module available at https://code.launchpad.net/~zorba-coders/zorba/data-converters-module
Instructions on how to install zorba with non core modules are available at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/documentation/2.5.0/zorba/modules_building_in